# Merging DataFrames in Pandas with Common Column, but Different Lengths and Values - Python 3.8.3, Pandas 1.0.5

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.8

I am generating dataframes from hdf5 datasets in a h5td file. These datasets are typically very large and I need to merge them. The general format is as follows:

group1/dataset1
group1/dataset1_Time
group1/dataset2
group1/dataset2_Time
group2/dataset3
group2/dataset3_Time
...

within the group, the times are typically (not always) the same, but I am trying to validate different datasets against each other, so I'm hoping to merge them on that common time axis and fill the gaps with "nan".

What I've tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import h5py

with h5py.File(filename,'r') as hfid:
    #create dataframes (I'm using group1 and group2)
    #Using a common time name
    timeName = "time"

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=[timeName,data1Name])
    df1[timeName] = hfid["group1/dataset1_Time"][:]
    df1[dataName] = hfid["group1/dataset1"][:]

    df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=[timeName,data3Name])
    df2[timeName] = hfid["group2/dataset3_Time"][:]
    df2[dataName] = hfid["group2/dataset3"][:]

#Merge the DataFrames
#Method 1:
df = df1.append(df2) #Works when no timestamps are shared (they sometimes are)

#Method2:
df = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=timeName,how="left") #Works only for DataFrames with the same timestamps
```

I need a way to merge these dataframes appropriately that won't lose any data and make rows like the following table where data3 occurs twice as often as data1:

| time | data1 | data3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100.5 | 0 | 1 |
| 100.6 | nan | 1 |
| 100.7 | 0 | 1 |
| 100.8 | nan | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

I find that stack overflow is typically easier to find than proper documentation.

According to [pandas.DataFrame.merge documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

I'm looking for the how="outer" argument to use the union of the keys.

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,how="outer")
```